# Flattening a pandas dataframe by creating new columns resulting in unique ID pairs

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transform

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
   id sid X_animal X_class Y_animal Y_class
0   1   A       88    Home   Monkey  Mammal
1   1   A       88    Home   Parrot    Bird
2   1   B
3   2   C       11    Work
4   2   C       11    Work
5   2   C       33  School      Dog  Mammal
6   3   D       44    Home   Salmon    Fish
7   3   D       44    Home     Bear  Mammal
8   3   D       44    Home      Dog  Mammal
9   4   E       55  School
```

and I want to flatten it so each id pairing (`id`, `sid`) is unique across rows. In this process, I want to create new columns from columns `*_animal` and `*_class` when their values differ for a given unique id pair. This is the dataframe I want:

```
   id sid X_animal_1 X_class_1 X_animal_2 X_class_2 Y_animal_1 Y_class_1 Y_animal_2 Y_class_2 Y_animal_3 Y_class_3
0   1   A         88      Home                          Monkey    Mammal     Parrot      Bird
1   1   B
2   2   C         11      Work         33    School        Dog    Mammal
3   3   D         44      Home                          Salmon      Fish       Bear    Mammal        Dog    Mammal
4   4   E         55    School
```

To build the initial and final dataframes, the code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

cols = ['id', 'sid', 'X_animal', 'X_class', 'Y_animal', 'Y_class']
l = [
    [1, 'A', 88, 'Home', 'Monkey', 'Mammal'],
    [1, 'A', 88, 'Home', 'Parrot', 'Bird'],
    [1, 'B', nan, nan, nan, nan],
    [2, 'C', 11, 'Work', nan, nan],
    [2, 'C', 11, 'Work', nan, nan],
    [2, 'C', 33, 'School', 'Dog', 'Mammal'],
    [3, 'D', 44, 'Home', 'Salmon', 'Fish'],
    [3, 'D', 44, 'Home', 'Bear', 'Mammal'],
    [3, 'D', 44, 'Home', 'Dog', 'Mammal'],
    [4, 'E', 55, 'School', nan, nan],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=l, columns=cols)
print(df.fillna(''))

cols2 = ['id', 'sid', 'X_animal_1', 'X_class_1', 'X_animal_2', 'X_class_2', 'Y_animal_1', 'Y_class_1', 'Y_animal_2', 'Y_class_2', 'Y_animal_3', 'Y_class_3']
l2 = [
    [1, 'A', 88, 'Home', nan, nan, 'Monkey', 'Mammal', 'Parrot', 'Bird'],
    [1, 'B', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
    [2, 'C', 11, 'Work', 33, 'School', 'Dog', 'Mammal', nan, nan],
    [3, 'D', 44, 'Home', nan, nan, 'Salmon', 'Fish', 'Bear', 'Mammal', 'Dog', 'Mammal'],
    [3, 'E', 55, 'School', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=l2, columns=cols2)
print(df2.fillna(''))
```

I've tried using `pivot()` and `pivot_table()` with no success. The variable amount of columns creates issues with that approach, giving me a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 3):

This is also known as pivot with two columns, basically, you need to enumerate the rows within a group before pivoting:

```
out = (df.assign(count=df.groupby(['id','sid']).cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(['id','sid'],columns='count')
   .fillna('')
)

# gets rid of column-wise duplicates
out = out.mask(out.groupby(level=0, axis=1).transform(lambda g: g.duplicated()))

out.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in out.columns]
out = out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id sid X_animal_1 X_animal_2 X_animal_3 X_class_1 X_class_2 X_class_3 Y_animal_1 Y_animal_2 Y_animal_3 Y_class_1 Y_class_2 Y_class_3
0   1   A         88                            Home                         Monkey     Parrot               Mammal      Bird
1   1   B
2   2   C         11                    33      Work              School                              Dog                        Mammal
3   3   D         44                            Home                         Salmon       Bear        Dog      Fish    Mammal
4   4   E         55                          School
```

Comment: This answer populates too many columns, for example, X_animal_2 has values 88, 11, and 44 which should be empty/nan/''.

Comment: You can maybe add `out = out.mask(out.groupby(level=0, axis=1).transform(lambda g: g.duplicated()))` to mask the duplicated values just before the MultiIndex flattening.

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 10 rows, received array of length 2` from `.pivot(['id','sid'],columns='count')`

Comment: What version of pandas are you using, @quang-hoang?

Comment: FYI - this works with pandas 1.1.4, but does not work with 1.0.3

Comment: @mozway I've included your suggestion in the edits, however, it results in empty X_animal_2 and X_class_2 columns which should have the contents of X_animal_3 and X_class_3, and the X_animal_3 and X_class_3 columns should be removed. I am looking into doing this

Comment: `pivot` accepts an array as index argument since `1.1.4`. For lower pandas version, use `pivot_table` instead.